# Grails rendering blank page

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails 2.3.11.

When I'm going to `localhost:8080/myapp/questionnaire/show/3`, application shows a blank page. And debug won't even step into any of the methods below.

```
class QuestionnaireController {

def beforeInterceptor = [action: this.&loadQuestionnaire, only: ['show']]

Questionnaire questionnaireInstance

def show = {
    render(view: 'show', model: [questionnaire: questionnaireInstance])
}

private def loadQuestionnaire() {
    questionnaireInstance = Questionnaire.findById(params.id)

    if(!questionnaireInstance) {
        redirectWhenNotFound(params.id)
    }
}

private def redirectWhenNotFound(def id) {
    flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [
            message(code: 'questionnaire.label'),
            id
    ])
    redirect(uri: "/")
}
```

However, When I try `localhost:8080/myapp/questionnaire/show`, it goes to `loadQuestionnaire()`, obviously can't find domain instance, because of `params.id` not existing, so it goes to `redirectWhenNotFound()` and redirects it properly to the main page.

Question is - why is it not working normally?

**Edit**:

It shows a blank page only when there is an instance with the given id, when there isn't, it goes into the method.

*Eventually I found out the solution, which is in the answer below.*

Comment: Have you tried without the `beforeInterceptor` and without the `questionnaireInstance`?  It seems like this could be done in a simpler way and holding onto instance variables within a controller isn't generally a good idea.

Comment: @tylerwal this project has a very similar example, the difference is redirect with `action` in the same controller, not `uri`. And if you say state it's not a good idea, it would be nice to justify this opinion. It may not be the-best-there-is idea, but it allows to simplify code and to not repeat the same steps in many methods. DRY.

Comment: My initial comment was in regards to the believe that Controllers would have been singleton-scoped and risk concurrency issues, but after looking into it they are actually request-scoped and the issue isn't as great.  I still think this code can be condensed and written in a simpler way without the interceptor.

Comment: And are you aware that this is not the only action in the controller? You are making completely off-topic comments, and even if they would be "on topic", you do not provide any *better* solution (to what exactly?)... I am sorry, but I cannot see the point. IMHO it would be better to remove these comments, if you are not up to providing useful information, nor any piece of actual advise.

Comment: I'm not trying to offend you - the point of a comment is to `ask for more information or suggest improvements`.  I'm not proposing an answer to your question of why your controller is rendering a blank page, therefore I'm not posting an answer, but I am suggesting an improvement.  It just seems that the fetching of `Questionnaire` would be improved as an action argument as opposed to within an interceptor: `def show(@RequestParameter('id')Questionnaire questionnaireInstance ) = {` and then redirect if necessary within the action.

Comment: Now that could be in fact an improvement, thank you, you just could've written that it in a first place. Anyway, that approach with interceptor is used in some other places in the project and seemed quite sensible to me. Besides, it works without this problem. Yet I'm still learning Grails, so I will definitely read something more about your way and maybe change it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking few more things, that it only fails when there is an instance with the given id, and it goes through the method when there is no instance with the given id, it turned out **there has been a misspelled column** in a `questionnaire` table, after editing it, Grails updated the schema and not deleted the old one.

Probably this was the problem, because I dropped that column, removed all rows, restarted application, created a new instance and it works now.

The problem was that it was failing silently, so I am leaving this answer for anyone, who might be having the same problem in the future.